plotting a confusion matrix with 4 clusters
given 4 confusion matrices:
c1 = RRRRBBGG
c2 = bbrrggg
c3 = rrrrb
c4 = gggbrr
how can we plot a confusion matrix and assess TN, TP, FN, FP
I understand how to do this if given more information, but I am unsure as to how to solve this question with only this information
thanks

Welcome to Cross Validated! A confusion matrix requires pairings of true and predicted categories. What are your pairings? Right now, it is really difficult to understand what you are asking (though if this is literally all you are given, you are not alone in being lost). For instance, we do not know what the letters mean or why there is a mix of capital and lowercase letters.
